# node.js socket.io client and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, npm

I want to run the simplest demo of socket.io from http://socket.io

The server (app.js) seems to work fine.

But I have trouble with the client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Where exactly should I point tho the the first script src ?

Of course I don't have the path

> /socket.io/socket.io.js

In the public folder of my webserver

My installation is as follow:

Installing node:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.12.tar.gz -P /tmp
mkdir ~/opt
cd ~/opt
tar zxvf /tmp/node-v0.4.12.tar.gz
cd node-v0.4.12
PREFIX=~/opt ./configure
make
make install
echo 'export PATH=~/opt/bin:${PATH}' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

test:

```
which node
```

returns:

> /home/wopi/opt/bin/node

test:

```
node -v
```

returns:

> v0.4.12

Installing NodePackageManager:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

test:

```
which npm
```

returns:

> /home/wopi/opt/bin/npm

test:

```
npm -v
```

returns

> 1.0.106

```
npm install socket.io
```

returns:

> socket.io@0.8.7 ./node_modules/socket.io
>
> ├── redis@0.6.7
>
> ├── policyfile@0.0.4
>
> └── socket.io-client@0.8.7

So how I should point to the correct js files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to point the JavaScript resource to:

```
your_ip:port_which_socket_io_isrunning/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

Example:

```
127.0.0.1:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

So checkout the port on which the Socket.IO has started..

Comment: O, It was not clear to me to point it to the running node instance... thx

Comment: @astropanic how did you exactly start your node instance for serving socket.io.js?

Comment: Is there any difference if you simplyp move the socket.io.js file from the server to the client's lib folder (same as how you'd install jquery, etc.)?

Comment: Figured it out pretty quick; socket.io.js requires Node, which is only server-side. So you do have to host the src remotely

Answer (score 0):

/socket.io/socket.io.js is built-in to the socket.io server code. You do not have to host it on a separate server.